# Inverting a matrix from LU decomposition

Tags: lapack, matrix-factorization

The LAPACK routines xGETRI compute the inverse of a matrix $A = PLU$ in its LU decomposed form by first computing $U^{-1}$, and then solving the system:
$$
(A^{-1} P) L = U^{-1}
$$
My question is: wouldn't it be more numerically stable to compute $L^{-1}$ since $L$ is a unit lower triangular matrix, and thus has determinant 1. Then you could solve:
$$
U (A^{-1} P) = L^{-1}
$$
for the matrix $A^{-1} P$. The matrix $U$ is not unit triangular, so inverting it could lead to problems if it is close to singular. It seems the alternative scheme of inverting $L$ would be more numerically stable, so I am curious if anyone know why LAPACK chose to invert $U$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reasoning is as follows:

When one stores the LU decomposition, the **diagonal** (factorized) of the matrix is stored in $U$, that's why it is not unit-triangular. This is a choice, and one could have opted for storing it in $L$.

Now, the fact that the matrix is not-invertible, does not mean that it does not have LU factorization. Take a look at [`getrf`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-getrf) description for the `info` output parameter:

> `info=i`, $u_{ii}$ is 0. The factorization has been completed, but $U$ is exactly singular. Division by $0$ will occur if you use the factor $U$ for solving a system of linear equations.

So, there, technically, is no error in [`getrf`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-getrf) call resultant in a non-zero positive `info` parameter. However, the usefulness of the result is questionable, since both the solution of the system of linear equations, as well as the inversion via [`getri`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-getri) will result in an error.

So, during the inversion via `getri`, the invertibility is determined by $U$. Hense, the choice.

I do not see, why would you avoid problems when the matrix is close to singular by flipping what is inverted, you probably would just postpone them until the multiplication by $U$ **with very small diagonal entries** (in case of close-to-singularness) in case of 
$$
U (A^{-1} P) = L^{-1}
$$

compared to solving against a RHS **with very large entries** in $U^{-1}$ in case of
$$
(A^{-1} P) L = U^{-1}
$$

<del>Moreover, pivoting is also involved.</del> This is straightforward (assuming $A$ and $U$ are invertible)
$$
A=PLU \Rightarrow I=A^{-1}PLU\Rightarrow U^{-1}=A^{-1}PL
$$
<del>I am not sure how to get to $L^{-1}$ version (assuming $A$ and $L$ are invertible) without the change of how pivoting $P$ is applied:</del>
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{aligned}
A=PLU \Rightarrow I=PLUA^{-1} &\Rightarrow \cancel{?}\\
&\Rightarrow P=PLUA^{-1}P\Rightarrow I=LUA^{-1}P\Rightarrow L^{-1}=UA^{-1}P
\end{aligned}
$$

<del>Thus, pivoting $P$ has to change to:</del>
$$
\require{cancel}\cancel{A=LU\tilde{P}\Rightarrow I=LU\tilde{P}A^{-1}\Rightarrow L^{-1}=U\tilde{P}A^{-1}}
$$

<del>which would imply a lot of other issues without obvious benefits.</del>

Comment: Interesting and you are probably correct. I just want to point out you don't need to change the pivoting for the $L^{-1}$ version: $I = PLUA^{-1} \Rightarrow P = PLUA^{-1}P \Rightarrow I = LUA^{-1}P \Rightarrow L^{-1} = UA^{-1} P$.

Comment: @vibe does not it has to assume that $P$ is invertible (step 2 in your derivation in the comments)?

Comment: @vibe and now I have a question to myself if $P$ is always invertible (which it should be....) :)

Comment: The determinant of a permutation matrix is always 1 or -1, so they are invertible. In fact they form a group under matrix multiplication https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = PLU$ be an LU decomposition, where $A$ is $n\times n$. Note that $U = D(I+N)$ where $D$ is diagonal, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $N$ is strictly upper-triangular. Now note that $(I+N)^{-1} = I + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} (-1)^k N^k$, and so $U^{-1} = \left(I + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} (-1)^k N^k \right) D^{-1}$, which can be computed pretty efficiently it you look at it hard enough. You can invert $L$ the same way, the only difference is you don't scale the columns of the "factorization" by $D^{-1}$. So it seems to me that the two procedures are pretty much equivalent, it just depends on if you want to scale by $D^{-1}$ at the start when "inverting" your triangular matrix, or at the end when solving the system.

Comment: I found a reference: Du Croz and Higham, Stability of methods for matrix inversion, IMA J. Num. Anal., 1992. They analyze several methods of inverting a matrix, including $A^{-1} = U^{-1} L^{-1}$, $A^{-1} L = U^{-1}$, and a couple others, and find they are all roughly equivalent in terms of numerical stability. Interestingly, LAPACK chose the $A^{-1} L = U^{-1}$ method, which requires extra workspace, while the $U^{-1} L^{-1}$ method requires no extra workspace.